# How to display selected records using Datatables plugin in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatables

To display selected records with datatables, if (documentType != X)

How to implement the above using Datatables, the code below is already implemented and working. It gets data from a JSON after Ajax calls and populates a table.

```
columnDefs: [
                {"width": "20%", targets: 0},
                {"width": "40%", targets: 1},
                {"width": "40%", targets: 2} //Set the width
            ],
            columns: [
                {"data": "documentType"},
                {"data": "fileName"}, //Display Linked file name
                {"data": "documentDate"} 
            ],
            aoColumnDefs: [ {
                    "aTargets": [ 1 ],
                    "mData": "fileName",
                    "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                        return '<a href="'+full.link+'">'+full.fileName+'</a>'; //Supply link to file
                    }
            }]
```

Comment: So you want to filter the table and display only those records where `documentType != "some-value"`?

Comment: yes, i want to display if documentType != "some-value"

Comment: Is there a reason you can't filter the data before it get displayed in the datatable?

Comment: I want to filter it in datatables only, as it must have a way which i do not know because i am a new user.